# Which one is better between data loader vs SSIS (Sql server integration services ) when import bulk data to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, import, ssis

I have more than 100 million records data in file txt. I would like to import them to SQL server. So, which one I can choose between data loader and SSIS. Thank you so much!

Comment: what do you mean when you say "data loader"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to the `Import Data` wizard when you say "The data loader", it is just a wizard that creates you an SSIS package to import your data.  You even get the option to save your import as an SSIS package at the end of the process.

If you care more about the speed of the import, for 100 million records within a text file you would *probably* (but not definitely) be better off using the [Bulk Copy Program (BCP) Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) provided by Mircosoft.

---

## Edit following comments

From what I can see, DataLoader.io is a Salesforce only tool.  It seems you cannot use it to load data into SQL Server.  In this case, out of the two options you have suggested SSIS is the only viable option.  Whether or not SSIS is suitable for your current and on-going situation however, is a larger discussion not really suited to the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: There are many import tools called Data loader: (1) https://dataloader.io/  (2) https://www.dbload.com/delimited-text-files-to-ms-sql-server.htm and more. I think the OP should be more precise by providing more details

Comment: @Yahfoufi  You are correct, which is why I was deliberate in stating my assumtion in my answer.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I mean dataloader.io vs SSIS. In the import process, I need filter data and I also add some columns that txt file hasn't before inserting data to database

Comment: It looks like dataloader.io is specifically for sales force. This is completely different to SSIS. If you specifically want to load data into salesforce then you should use their tool